# Symfony's DomCrawler how can I extract meta description from html source

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony's DomCrawler how can I extract meta description from html source?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addHtmlContent($html->content, 'UTF-8');

$title = $crawler->filter('title')->text();
```

Example MSN meta description

```
<meta name="description" content="The new MSN, Your customizable collection of the best in news, sports, entertainment, money, weather, travel, health, and lifestyle, combined with Outlook, Facebook, Twitter, Skype, and more."/>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you are trying to get content attribute value so try to use

```
$data = $crawler->filterXpath("//meta[@name='description']")->extract(array('content'));
```

and loop through `$data`.

Answer (score 6):

```
$meta_description = $crawler->filter('meta[name="description"]')->eq(0)->attr('content');
```